# Send a direct message to someone's rocketChat account using rocketChat API

Tags: rocket.chat

Is it possible to send a direct message from my RocketChat Account to another account using RocketChat API ([RocketChat Rest API](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/))?

I've looked around the API documentation but I didn't find what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used code below:

```
let RocketChat = require('rocketchat-nodejs').Client;
let Client = new RocketChat({
  host: 'myHost',
  port: 80,
  scheme: 'http',
  username: 'myUser',
  password: 'myPass'
});
let Authentication = Client.Authentication();
let Users = Client.Users();
let Chat = Client.Chat();

Client.login().then(() => {
  Authentication.me().then((result) => {
    Users.list({ userId: 'muUser' }).then((result) => {
      var list = result;
      Chat.postMessage({ roomId: list.users[0]._id, text: 'test'})
        .then((result) => {
        })
    });
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```